# POST to Python Flask server from Node / Express: OSError: Invalid chunk header

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to post some json to a python flask server and am getting the following error:

```
OSError: Invalid chunk header
```

**header params**

```
let apiParams = {
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    port: "5000",
    path: "/",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
};
```

**the post request:**

```
generatePostRequest(apiParams) {
        let req = http.request(apiParams, function (res) {
            console.log('Status: ' + res.statusCode);
            console.log('Headers: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            res.on('data', function (body) {
                console.log('Body: ' + body);
            });
            req.on('error', function(e) {
                console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
            });
        });
        return req;
}
 let req = this.generatePostRequest(apiParams);
 req.write(JSON.stringify({text:"this is only a test"}));
```

**console.log output**

```
Headers: {"content-type":"application/json","content-length":"37","server":"Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.7.0","date":"Fri, 12 Oct 2018 17:46:23 GMT"}
Body: {"message": "Internal Server Error"}
```

**simple get request works**

```
getRequest() {
        let res = fetch('http://0.0.0.0:5000') 
        .then((response) => {        
             return response.json();
        })    
        .then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        })
        .catch(function(e) {      
            console.log(e);
        });    
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: It's been too long since I last used Python and Werkzeug, but perhaps [this issue](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1094) might provide some insight. Instead of using `req.write(JSON.stringify(...))`, does `req.end(JSON.stringify(...))` work?

Comment: @robertklep unfortunately req.end(stringified json) didn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: Still the same error when you're using `res.end()`? Because in that situation, the request isn't being chunked by Node (since the content length is known) and perhaps there's another part in your stack (a proxy?) that is chunking it again.

Comment: Would Flask chunk it again?

Comment: @robertklep req.end or res.end? I believe you mean req.end()? Anyway, when I add req.end() I do not get a chunking error, I am getting another error which I'm parsing through - perhaps req.end did the trick - will update, thanks!

Comment: Sorry yeah, `req.end(...)`. If you don't get a chunking error, what _do_ you get?

Comment: @robertklep - I updated the SO post with the error, I believe your req.end() suggestion resolved the issue, working on debugging and if your suggestion is the correct one would you mind submitting it as the answer so I can mark it as the accepted solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using `req.write()`, Node.js will default to using ["chunked transfer encoding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), which means that each call to `req.write()` will send a chunk of data to the HTTP server, preceded by a bytecount.

My guess is that Werkzeug is timing out, because you're not ending the request (so Werkzeug is expecting a new chunk, or an end-of-request, but isn't getting it and at some point it throws an error).

To end the request, you need to explicitly call `req.end()` when you're done:

```
let req = this.generatePostRequest(apiParams);
req.write(JSON.stringify({text:"this is only a test"}));  
req.end();
```

Or, if you have a fixed amount of data to send, you can combined `req.write` and `req.end`:

```
let req = this.generatePostRequest(apiParams);
req.end(JSON.stringify({text:"this is only a test"}));
```

Comment: Hi @roberklep I'm getting the 'OSError: Invalid Chunk Header' in an Flask app when sending a request through curl, for example `curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload-file/ -F file=@./test.html` and trying to access `request.form['file']`. Any idea what the problem is here?

Comment: @Kemeia sorry, I don't know Flask well enough to help you out :(

Comment: Turned out the I was sending a non-existing file.... Thanks for the reply!